# L2PT VPN Server with windows 10

Tags: windows-10, vpn, l2tp

Is it possibile to add a **L2TP VPN server** service in Windows 10? As far as I know only PPTP vpn is available.

Comment: Why would L2TP be the preference when its throughput is substantially slower than OpenVPN or Wiregaurd _(e.g. it's inefficient and must be used along with IPsec)_?

Comment: Because OpenVPN needs a custom client for Android and Windows devices.

Comment: L2TP has been obsolete for a while, though it's still used, as it's fundamentally inefficient and it can't be made efficient because IPsec is inefficient _(L2TP doesn't support encryption & is why it's always married to IPSec)_, which is why throughput will always significantly lag when compared to an SSL VPN [OpenVPN] or WireGuard _(most efficient of all VPNs)_. Simply because a client program is needed shouldn't be a hindrance _(with Android, [OpenVPN for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.blinkt.openvpn) is the best app, as it allows full customization of the config)_

Comment: What about IKEv2? It looks like it can work with many default clients (Windows and Android)

Comment: I'm not familiar with IKEV2 and have spent the last 15min on search engines trying to find throughput results and haven't come up with any, so I can't comment without being able to compare throughput speeds between it and OpenVPN and WireGuard. Generally speaking, WireGaurd outperforms all VPN protocols and provided OpenVPN is tuned correctly _(tuned [example](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/tree/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenVPN))_, it usually outperforms all other VPN protocols except WireGuard _(OpenVPN generic configs should not be used, as they won't result in the best throughput)_